Python-esque film set in boarding school and/or possibly army camp?
I saw a British comedy in the early 90s, but believe it to have been made in the 70s or 80s judging by the look of it. It was very Python-esque and may have even included some of the Monty Python lot. I remember a boarding school and/or an army camp, and possibly a tiger (though I believe I may be mixing up some memories between this and The Meaning of Life). I know this is vague, but if someone knew the film I was talking about I'd be very happy!

This may be the TV Show Ripping Yarns rather than a film.
The first episode was called "Tomkinson's Schooldays" and was set in a boarding school. "Roger of the Raj" involves the British Army in India. 
wiki
imdb




It was definitely Ripping Yarns - looking forward to watching more of them. They were previously a hazy memory from my early teens!
